# intermittent NoNodeAvailableException

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my function to query Elastic:

```java
public static SearchHits queryES(String index, QueryBuilder builder) throws UnknownHostException {
        TransportAddress address = new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300);
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", Config.ES_CLUSTER_NAME)
                .put("client.transport.sniff", false)
                .build();

        org.elasticsearch.client.Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(address);

        return client.prepareSearch(index).setQuery(builder).get().getHits();
    }
```

All the variables in `elasticsearch.yml` seem to be correct. However, after I run this code for like 400-500 successful calls to this function (it returns the correct data) in less than 1 minute, I got a `NoNodeAvailableException`. Then nearly all subsequent calls get this exception. It does recover sometimes, then `NoNodeAvailableException` again.

I run ES 6.2.2 on my PC, transport client version is also the latest. The health status is `YELLOW`. What could be the reason for my repeated `NoNodeAvailableException`?

EDIT: an example of the exception:

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{-MmALnp3SKu1JUqXLPJ86w}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
```

Comment: did you find any answer? i'm facing the same issue

Comment: @VishalPatel No, I didn't find any real answer. I do remember that I use some kind of exponential backoff to throttle the request... I thought it is only ES on my hardware cannot handle such large traffic.